# Code runs fine in executable, same code requires elevated permissions in DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I am writing a WPF application which uses an OleDb Connection to read Paradox 7 Tables and push the data into a SQL Database. It runs fine in my WPF executable when testing without administrator privileges. More recently I wanted to separate UI and functionality, so I broke that code into an assembly (DLL) of its own.

Since moving it to a DLL, the code only works when run elevated, and I can't understand why...

Any and all answers/explanations appreciated!

The exception I get when I try to run any query from the OleDbConnection:
`Unexpected error from external database driver (11265).`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks The exception I get when I try to run a query is: Unexpected error from external database driver (11265).

Answer (score 1):

Might have to do with *where* your Paradox tables are saved on disk.  If they're in "program files", for example... yes, you'll need elevated privileges!